# How to convert int to string in nan, C++?

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

So, I got that:

```
void Method(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info) {
    v8::Local<v8::Context> context = info.GetIsolate()->GetCurrentContext();
    int last_number = info[0]->NumberValue(context).FromJust();
    info.GetReturnValue().Set(Nan::New<(fib(last_number)));
}
```

https://github.com/nodejs/nan is used here
I need to return a string value from this function. Function fib returns an int value. Any way to convert int to string here gives me different errors.

Comment: what errors? Does `std::to_string` not work for you?

Comment: btw the return type is `void` and parameter passed as `cosnt &`, its not clear how you are planning to return a string

Answer (score 0):

If `s` is a `const char *`, then:

```
if (!s) {
  info.GetReturnValue().Set(Nan::Null());
} else {
  info.GetReturnValue().Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(s).ToLocalChecked());
}
```